# How to access an object that is in a Managed Bean?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I'm using JSF 2.2.

For example, i had a form:

```
<section class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="flat-textbox" id="names" placeholder="Nombres"/>
</section>
<section class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="flat-textbox" id="surnames" placeholder="Apellidos"/>
</section>
<section class="form-group">
    <input type="datetime" class="flat-textbox" id="birth-date" 
           placeholder="F. Nacimiento"/>
</section>
```

And i wanna bind player with each input:

```
<input type="text" class="flat-textbox" id="names"
       jsf:value="#{playerbean.player.names} placeholder="Nombres"/>
```

The bean is:

```
@Named(value="playerbean")
@RequestScoped
public class PlayerBean {
    @Inject private PlayerServiceImpl playerService;
    @Inject private PlayerVO player; // i want set properties from view form

    // methods...
}
```

What options do I have for it?

- Add `Named(value="player")` annotation to `PlayerVO` class?
- Add a getter for player into Bean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing accessors for the property you want to modify, should be just enough.

Do:

```
public PlayerVO getPlayer() { return player; }
public void setPlayer(PlayerVO player) { this.player = player; }
```

and:

```
<input type="text" class="flat-textbox" 
       id="names" jsf:value="#{playerbean.player.names}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. So, this are good?

`<input type="text" class="flat-textbox" id="names" jsf:value="#{playerbean.getPlayer().names}"/>`